# Select não retorna valor quebrado

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Tenho o seguinte comando:

```
 SELECT CAST(450/4 AS DECIMAL(15,2))
```

**Retorno**: *112 onde o certo seria 112.5*

Porque disso?

*OBS: Meu SCRIPT está em uma procedure, mas de grosso modo meu problema está nesse select*

Comment: Segundo a documentação (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/divide-transact-sql), o tipo do retorno da divisão será o tipo de precedência mais alta, entre divisor e dividendo, e quando os dois são inteiros o resultado também é um inteiro e será truncado, Tente fazer assim, então: `450.0/4.0`, que provavelmente o resultado será do tipo `decimal`.

Comment: Está é precisamente a resposta @PedroGaspar-LoboFX. Poste-a como tal

Comment: Exatamente funcionou dessa forma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a documentação:

> / (Division) (Transact-SQL)
>   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/divide-transact-sql

o tipo do retorno da divisão será o tipo de precedência mais alta ([*Data type precedence*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql)), entre divisor e dividendo, e quando os dois são inteiros, o resultado também é um inteiro e será truncado.

Faça dessa forma, então, que o resultado da divisão será do tipo `decimal`:

```
SELECT CAST(450.0/4.0 AS DECIMAL(15,2))
```

Ao escrever uma constante numérica com ponto decimal, o SQL Server entenderá que aquele número é do tipo `decimal`:

> Constants (Transact-SQL)
>   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql

Como o tipo `decimal` tem precedência mais alta que `int`, creio que só uma das constantes poderia ser do tipo `decimal` para que o retorno fosse do tipo `decimal` também, então dessa forma:

```
450/4.0
```

ou dessa:

```
450.0/4
```

Também deve funcionar.